# undefined local variable or method `remote_avatar_url' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have mounted AvatarUploader as show in carrierwave docs

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
```

When I try to create an user with url

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user, remote_avatar_url => "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/14938353_1195336437213378_941804383137628957_n.jpg?oh=163a1fef88ec96558056094f60152976&oe=5A81C63F")`
```

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `remote_avatar_url' for main:Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a colon:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user, :remote_avatar_url => ...
                          ^
```

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `split' for #<URI::HTTPS:0x007f910407e9e0>):

Comment: ```
 FactoryGirl.create(:user, :remote_avatar_url => URI.parse("https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/14938353_1195336437213378_941804383137628957_n.jpg?oh=163a1fef88ec96558056094f60152976&oe=5A81C63F"))
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for #<URI::HTTPS:0x00000002f80528>
from /home/vamsi/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-1.0.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/download.rb:88:in `rescue in process_uri'
```